# How to Extract a Value from string Using Regular Expressions

Tags: java, regex, parsing

I have the following String :

```
XYZ,132917057937901,150617,051244,+12.345555,+73.179481,0,153,45,11,1,3,000,00,0.0,9.23,7.40,24.74,0.0,0,0.90,0,0,345,1374,108
```

Now i want to extract value at the 16th position `9.23` and 17th position `7.40`.

This string is fixed with their position.

How can i get value at 16th and 17th position ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `String.split` instead of regex:

```
String[] split = input.split(',');
String pos16 = split[15];
```

In case you do want to use regex, match using this and get groups 1 and 2:

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(?:[^,]*,){15}([^,]*),([^,]*)").matcher(input);
m.find();
String pos16 = m.group(1);
```

Comment: Regex does not match.  Remove `,` after `{15}`.